# wrong format in datepicker while loading data from single value query result

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datepicker, oracle-apex

I've such select in datepicker source:

```
select DATA_WYPOZYCZENIA from rezerwacje WHERE ID_REZERWACJI=:P110302_ID_REZ
```

After loading page item loads value with mask DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI but mask set in datepicker settings is DD-MON-YYYY. The result I want to get is to have date loaded from select i've written above int datepicker in format DD-MON-YYYY. Changing settings of mask attribute in intem setting do not change aything.

Comment: Try to explicitly print the date format you expect like, *to_char(urcolumn,'dd-MON-YYYY')* as date is displayed in default session parameter(_NLS_DATE_FORMAT_) when a format is not specified.

Comment: I've tried that, i put in source following sql:

Select to_char(select DATA_WYPOZYCZENIA from rezerwacje WHERE ID_REZERWACJI=:P110302_ID_REZ,'dd-MON-YYYY')  from dual;

But apex didn't accept that. In sql commands got error: ORA-00936: missing expression.

I don't understand this part of you comment:
 as date is displayed in default session parameter(NLS_DATE_FORMAT) when a format is not specified. –  

Could you write it in other words, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATE` is a `RAW` datatype. When we attempt to print it, there has to be some format. But *NOT* Every SQL doesn't have that format specified.

For this reason, the `DBMS` has some default date format in their set up, which is local to the db session. Oracle names these default parameters as [NLS_PARAMETERS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/server.816/a76966/ch2.htm). And [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/server.816/a76966/ch2.htm#94690) is the one that specifies the date format.

```
SELECT
     to_char(DATA_WYPOZYCZENIA,'dd-MON-YYYY') as DATA_WYPOZYCZENIA
FROM
     rezerwacje
WHERE
     ID_REZERWACJI=:P110302_ID_REZ
```

But when your client receives this query, the mapping could no more be Date datatype but String. Because, now we converted the date into a String with some format.

Comment: Glad it worked.....!! Please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark on left top of my answer! :)

Comment: I've clicked, but: Vote Up requires 15 reputation, so my vote is not acccepted currently.

Comment: @user3376246 It is not the vote, but a tick mark below the vote..! Please see [this link to check how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thicked, this time should be OK